# Angular view template content updates only on mouse over

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, angularjs-scope

I have a strange behavior using an Angular template with a controller . A special view content often updates on mouse over only. I have setup a few jsFiddles but cannot reproduce the problem. So it is obviously a mistake in my source code. The only special thing I see here is that I use a `$scope` method to format and display HTML content. `{{order.total()}} €` It is weird that it work sometimes.

All other HTML parts are updating as expected. Any idea what could be wrong?

[image]

```js
$scope.order = {
  _total : 0,
  total : function() {
    return Globalize.format(this._total, "n");
  },
  positions: []
};


$scope.addProductToCurrentOrder = function(packageIndex, productId) {

  var rs = {
    _id : productId
  };


  var tab = $scope.categories[packageIndex].packages;
  for (var i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
    var pack = tab[i];
    if (pack.productId === productId){
      pack.quantity++;
      rs.articleName = pack.name;
      rs.price = pack.price;
      rs._price = pack._price;
      rs.unit = pack.unit;
      rs.weight = pack.weight;
      break;
    }
  }
  $scope.order.positions.push(rs);
  $scope.order._total += rs._price;
};
```

```html
<h1>
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-large">{{order.total()}} €</span>
</h1>

<div data-id="{{package.productId}}" class="btn bt-default panel panel-default order order-card withripple" ng-click="addProductToCurrentOrder($parent.$index, package.productId)">
   <div class="panel-body">
     <p class="lead">  {{package.name}}</p> 
     <p>{{package.weight}} {{package.unit}}</p>
       </div>
 <div class="ripple-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there might be no reason your expression not be working, so instead I will

- remove Globalize function call, then see what is going on with Globalize.
- compute globalize string when recomputing new  Total.
- use of filter() angular expression to compute globalization.

What is the library behind ?

Mock Globalize function

```
var Globalize = {
  format : function(a,b) {
     return 22;   
  }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/darul75/5L2d9y75/

Comment: I already tried to remove Globalize. And I just tried to use ngFilter without success. Abstract... I figured out that it has something to do with used CSS classes. It works when I remove all classed totally. So I guess there is something going on in bootstrap or other libs I use. Anyway thanks for your help.