# Having issue related to $scope variable in AngularJS. Value is not changed in UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The value of image isn't updated in the UI, even though the scope variable is changed.

Main Controller :

```
$scope.TVuploadModal = function($files) {
                $scope.TvTemp.file = $files[0];
                $scope.TvTemp.fileName = $files[0].name
                var fileReader = new FileReader();
                fileReader.readAsDataURL($scope.TvTemp.file);
                fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                    $timeout(function() { $scope.TvTemp.file.dataUrl = e.target.result; });
                };
                $scope.ResourceOpenBannerImageCrop('lg');
            }
            $scope.ResourceOpenBannerImageCrop = function(size) {
                $modal.open({ templateUrl: 'BannerImageCrop.html', controller: 'resourceBannerImageCropCtrl', backdrop: 'static', size: size, scope: $scope,
                    resolve: {
                        TVImages: function () {
                          return $scope.TVImages;
                        }
                      }
                }).result.then(function(images) { 
                    console.log("Hello.....");
                    console.log($scope.TVImages);
                /*$scope.TVImages = images;*/ });
            };
```

resourceBannerImageCropCtrl :

```
app.controller('resourceBannerImageCropCtrl', function($scope,$rootScope,TVImages,$routeParams, $modalInstance, $location, $upload,ResourceAdditionStepsUpdateService,mediaUploadService) {
    $scope.myCroppedImage = '';   
    $scope.TVImages1 = TVImages;
    $scope.showSpinner = false;
    $scope.imageCrop = function() {
        $scope.showSpinner = true;
        var requestMap = { imagedata:$scope.myCroppedImage, fileName:$scope.TvTemp.fileName, fileType:"Resource Images", userId: $rootScope.currentLoggedInUserId }
        var saveResourceImages = mediaUploadService.saveImagesToUserBucket(requestMap, function(response) {
            $scope.showSpinner = false;
            if (response.isSuccess) {
                var image = {}
                image.uniqueKey = response.data.uniqueKey
                image.fileUrl = response.data.url
                image.fileType  = "Resource Images"
                image.description = $scope.description  
                image.type = "IMAGE"
                image.s3UploadStatus = response.data.s3UploadStatus
                    ResourceAdditionStepsUpdateService.saveResourceImages({resourceId : $scope.resourceMetadata.resourceData.id , image : image},function(response){
                        console.log(response.data.mediaList);
                        $scope.showSpinner = false;
                        if(response.isSuccess){
                            $scope.TVImages1 = [];
                             $scope.TVImages1 = response.data.mediaList;
                             if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                                    $scope.$apply();
                                }
                        }
                    });
                $modalInstance.close(/*$scope.volcareTVImages*/);
            }
        })
    };
    $scope.cancel = function() { $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 mb20" ng-repeat="image in TVImages">
   //content
</div>
```

I am passing the scope variable (i.e `$scope.TVImages`) in `resolve` as you can see in the code I am updating the `$scope.TVImages1`.

As per my understanding of two way data binding, if `$scope.TVImages1` is updated, then `$scope.TVImages` should also update via the `resolve`.

I also tried using `$scope.$apply`, but that didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I experienced a similar behavior with angular described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27166901/angular-view-template-content-updates-only-on-mouse-over. Can u try to remove all assets that have nothing to do with your angular logic?

Answer (score 0):

Qasim,

Some days ago, I was also facing this kind of issue while updating the value of **$scope variable** which is assigned as **ng-repeat variable** in the the view.

Could you please try to use following line instead of **$scope.TVImages**

**$rootScope.TVImages** that will update the view variable.

Please let me know if you still facing some problem.